# determine the probability that $\lfloor x+y\rfloor=\lfloor x \rfloor+\lfloor y \rfloor$ if $x,y$ chosen randomly,independently from $[1,1000]$

Tags: probability

> For two random positive real numbers and chosen uniformly and independently from the interval $[1,1000]$ , determine the probability that $\lfloor x+y\rfloor=\lfloor x \rfloor+\lfloor y \rfloor$

I want to do this using geometry.I was thinking of using straight lines where $\lfloor x+y \rfloor=c$,the equation becomes $c=\lfloor  x\rfloor+\lfloor y \rfloor.$Something like this.Please help.Just give me some hint. That will suffice.

I have a solution that looks like this If the fractional parts (portions after the decimal) add up to less than $1$, the two will be equal, otherwise unequal. The probability is zero that they'd add to exactly $1$, so that can be ignored. If the fractional parts are plotted on coordinate axes, the resulting unit square is divided by a diagonal line from $(0,1)$ to $(1,0)$  separating these two equal areas. The probability is $\dfrac{1}{2}$ But please help me understand how this is possible. It seems too handwavy for me.

Here, the only thing that matters are the decimals of x and y. There are two differents wways : either the sum of the decimals of x and y is $>1 $, or the sum of the decimals of x and y is $<1 $. These 2 cases therefore have the same probability : $1/2$. This demonstration is by no means rigorous; I simply used my logic. This also does not trigger just at an instant.

Comment: You say that you "want to do this using geometry." So, what geometric approaches have you tried? Where are you unsure about how to proceed?

Comment: @AaronMontgomery I was thinking of using straight lines where $\lfloor x+y \rfloor=c$,the equation becomes $c=\lfloor  x\rfloor+\lfloor y \rfloor.$Something like this

Comment: Note that the problem is exactly the same if you require $(x,y)\in[0,1]^2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

You may consider $\{x\} = x-[x]$, $\{y\} = y-[y]$. Then,

$$\{x\} + \{y\} <1$$
to get $[x+y] = [x] + [y]$

As I can see in your edit, you exactly did this. :-)

Comment: yes but I got swayed away. Simply put confused. Also see I have posted a solution which I do not like. This is not my solution. It is from some other source but  I am not satiated.

Comment: @Saradamani: Imagine your sample space as $[1,1000] \times [1,1000]$ divided into small squares $[k,k+1) \times [l,l+1)$. Now, you restrict your consideration to such a small square, as $[x]$ and $[y]$ lie in such a square. Mathematically one splits the sample space $\Omega$ into disjoint events $E_{k,l}$. Then, one shows that the considered event $E$ (here $[x+y] = [x] + [y]$) restricted to $E_{k,l}$ has exactly half the probability: $P(E\cap  E_{k,l}) = \frac{1}{2}P(E_{k,l})$. The cases for $x= 1000$ and $y= 1000$ can be ignored, as they have a probability of zero.

Comment: Yes @trancelocation that's the argument. You have hit the bullseye. Now I get it. Well, sadly you all are so good at reasoning. I am just so stupid. Thats a bummer.

Comment: @Saradamani: As I can see, you understand quite well clearly written explanations. Me too, I often get stuck with extremely shortened answers or carelessly written explanations. So, welcome to the club :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your desired geometric approach -- perhaps it could work, but it's not obvious to me how.

Instead, I'd try to think about how to categorize the essential aspects of $x$ and $y$ that will make that equation true. For instance:

- If $x = 3.2$ and $y = 2.4$, then the equation holds.
- If $x = 3.2$ and $y = 2.9$, then the equation does not hold.

So, what is it about the relationship between $x$ and $y$ that makes the equation work? Once you have that, you're much closer to having an answer. Let me know if you need more hints.

**EDIT:** Your proposed solution in your edited post looks good.

Comment: I request you to see my OP and please suggest whether this can be the reason why it is $1/2$

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to do using Geometry by drawing a straight line $\lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor y \rfloor =c$ where $c=\lfloor x+y \rfloor$ and using this I wanted to state that $x,y$ either lie on the straight line or above it and I presumed the answer was $2/3$ which was wrong.

Comment: Ah -- I think you've worked this out in the comments of another answer already, but the logic for why the two things have probability $1/2$ is *not* correct. (Proof: Suppose I considered whether $x + y < 0.5$ or $x + y > 0.5$. There are still two options here, but each of these can't have probability $1/2$ because certainly the probability that $x + y < 0.5$ is strictly less than the probability that $x + y < 1$.) Rather, the essential ingredient comes from drawing $[0, 1]^2$ and characterizing which parts of the set have the desired property. The area of that set happens to be $1/2$.

Comment: I apologize; I was not able to recognize this as being the "geometric approach" you outlined. (Specifically, I still don't know how your "straight line $\lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor y \rfloor = c$" or your other one relate to this problem at hand.) But yes, there is a modest amount of geometry at the back end of the problem.